# Open a file in my project folder with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use javascript to read a file called "orca.txt" to get a number (counter).
I tried to do that:

```js
var contador=0; 

var fr = new FileReader();  
fr.onload = function(e) {contador = e.target.result;};

fr.readAsText("orca.txt");
```

I know how to do that with an "input" but i don't want user choice a file... the file is always `orca.txt`
Can anyone help me?

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: That would be a huge security problem, if a script could freely choose the file that should be read.

Comment: It's not possible to read an arbitrary file on the user's computer since it would be a huge security vulnerability.

Comment: You can't. Just imagine if a page you load just try to load file on your computer. How would you react ?

Comment: You need to use a `file input` to initialise this sort of process

Comment: But it's not a file from user's computer... in my site, i've a file in folder, index.html must read it... it isnt an inputed file... Can I?

Comment: @Vollfeiw you re right... but i wanna read my file, in my server, just to get some configuration..

Comment: You might be able to use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) if the server is serving the file

Comment: Then you can't with javascript. Your javascript file is running on client side, not server side. If you need to get a document from your client side, you will have to make it public on your server, wich can be bad if this is a confidential file. In this case, you will need to have scripts running on server to read the file before (php could be a good start) sending the html page.

Comment: Thank you guys... i will try

Comment: Can you give more information about your server ? Are you running a node server ? Apache / nginx ? 

Can your txt file be used before serving the html file ?

Can it be served as a public file, or do you need it to be private ?

We could give you a slightly more precise answer by knowing what's your goal and setup.